# Create a python function procedurally (specifically the arguments)

Tags: python

### Question

How do you procedurally create a function in Python which takes specific named arguments but allow those argument names to be data-driven?

### Example

Say, you want to create a class decorator, `with_init`, which adds an `__init__` method with specific named arguments such that the following two classes are equivalent.

```
class C1(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

@with_init('x y z')
class C2(object):
    pass
```

My first attempt cheats by making a function which accepts `*args` instead of the specific named parameters:

```
class with_init(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params.split()

    def __call__(self, cls):
        def init(cls_self, *args):
            for param, value in zip(self.params, args):
                setattr(cls_self, param, value)
        cls.__init__ = init
        return cls
```

It works in some situations:

```
>>> C1(1,2,3)
<__main__.C1 object at 0x100c410>
>>> C2(1,2,3)
<__main__.C2 object at 0x100ca70>
```

But not so much in others:

```
>>> C2(1,2,3,4) # Should fail, but doesn't.
<__main__.C2 object at 0x100cc90>

>>> C2(x=1, y=2, z=3) # Should succeed, but doesn't.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

Of course I can add code to the nested `init` function to try and check for every possible situation, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

I've noticed that [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) avoids these issues by making a string to pass to `exec`. That seems very round-about to me, but perhaps that's the solution.

What is the correct implementation of `with_init.__call__`?

Note: I'd like a Python 2.x solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very roughly. This accepts kw args and checks to see that the number of args is correct

```
def __call__(self, cls):
    def init(cls_self, *args, **kw):
        if len(args)+len(kw) != len(self.params):
            raise RuntimeError("Wrong number of arguments")
        for param, value in zip(self.params, args):
            setattr(cls_self, param, value)
        vars(cls_self).update(kw)
    cls.__init__ = init
    return cls
```

This version has a few improvements

```
def __call__(self, cls):
    def init(cls_self, *args, **kw):
        for param, value in zip(self.params, args):
            if param in kw:
                raise TypeError("Multiple values for %s"%param)
            kw[param]=value
        if len(args) > len(self.params) or set(kw) != set(self.params):
            raise TypeError("Wrong number of arguments")
        vars(cls_self).update(kw)
    cls.__init__ = init
    return cls
```

This version also tells you about unexpected keyword args

```
def __call__(self, cls):
    def init(cls_self, *args, **kw):
        for param, value in zip(self.params, args):
            if param in kw:
                raise TypeError("Multiple values for %s"%param)
            kw[param]=value
        unexpected_args = list(set(kw)-set(self.params))
        if unexpected_args:
            raise TypeError("Unexpected args %s"%unexpected_args)
        missing_args = list(set(self.params)-set(kw))
        if missing_args:
            raise TypeError("Expected args %s"%missing_args)
        vars(cls_self).update(kw)
    cls.__init__ = init
    return cls
```

Comment: +1:  If someone thinks they want "dynamic" parameter names, they are just messing with `*args` and `**kw`.

Comment: Those errors aren't nearly as helpful as the real errors though. Compare `TypeError: Wrong number of arguments` to `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'w'`.

Comment: @Jon-Eric So change the error message.  You'll have to do more work to figure out the names of the unexpected/missing arguments, though.

Comment: @Jon-Eric, Not hard to do, but you see the code is getting longer and longer...maybe it's better to use `exec` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my namedtuple inspired answer. It's currently open to template injection attacks but you don't have to handle *any* of the parameter errors yourself.

```
def __call__(self, cls):
    paramtxt = ', '.join(['self'] + self.params)
    bodytxt =  '\n\t'.join('self.%(param)s = %(param)s' % locals() for param in self.params)
    template = 'def __init__(%(paramtxt)s):\n\t%(bodytxt)s' % locals()

    namespace = dict()
    exec template in namespace

    cls.__init__ = namespace['__init__']

    return cls
```

Comment: How is `exec` is open to injection attacks? Are you creating these classes from hostile user input? If you are just using them with hardcoded paramtxt/bodytxt there is no problem